# The conditional check item.mount is failed

Tags: python, ansible

My playbook does not understand my variable `DIRLOG` and `MOUNTS`, am I missing the hierarchy?

**STRUCTURE**

```
playbooks
|   └── start_linux.yml
|  
|   
roles
|  └── preRequirements
|      └── tasks
|          └── main.yml                         
group_vars
  └── main.yml
```

**TASKS**

```
    # Check space directory /var/logs/
      - name: 'Ensure that free space on /var/logs/ is grater than 1.5Gb'
        assert:
          that: item.size_available >= 1500000000
        when: item.mount == DIRLOG
        with_items: MOUNTS
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: disk_free

      - block:
          - debug:
              msg: "Disk (/var/logs/) space has reached 1.5Gb threshold"
          - meta: end_play
        when: disk_free is failed

  - debug:
      msg: "Sufficient disk space (/var/logs/), continue play"
```

**VARS**

```
#################################################################################
# Variables global
#################################################################################

DIRLOG        : '/var/logs/'
MOUNTS        : "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
```

**PLAYBOOK**

```
# playbook for linux
---
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - ../group_vars/all.yml
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Check Pre Requirements for install agent
      import_role:
        name: preRequirements
        tasks_from: main
```

**ERROR**

```
TASK [preRequirements : Ensure that free space on /var/logs/ is grater than 1.5Gb] ************************************************************************
fatal: [client_test]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.mount == DIRLOG' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.mount == DIRLOG): 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'mount'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/roles/preRequirements/tasks/main.yml': line 17, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n# Check space directory /var/logs/\n  - name: 'Ensure that free space on /var/logs/ is grater than 1.5Gb'\n    ^ here\n"}
...ignoring
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was simple, a few hours of research follows a solution:

```
gather_facts: yes
```

I will leave POST to help people with the same problem in the future

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gather_facts_module.html